# How can i overlay the outer div over the inner div?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

how can i overlay the blue div over the yellow div? I tried to add a relative position to the outer div, but i doesnt work.

```css
.c1{
  padding:25px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  
}
.c2{
top: 0; 
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
      Hallo Welt
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can have a child element behind his parent element with z-index. You have to give `z-index:-1;` and `position:absolute;` to the child div.
2. Also I'm sharing the link of a article for your reference that describes how you can use the stacking order of elements to allow the z-index to be negative in order to place an element behind it's parent.
   [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

```css
.c1{
  padding:25px;
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.c2{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
      Hallo Welt
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to CSS specifications, when using the `position: absolute` value, the element will always look for a positioned parent element (i.e. an element with `position: relative`) to act as a reference point. If no positioned parent is found, the element will default to the document body.

Additionally, when working with the `position` property, the `z-index` property only works on positioned elements (i.e. elements with a position value other than `static`).

```css
.c1 {
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.c2 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
      Hallo Welt
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```